# Regular expression to remove all lines that begin with a specific symbol and more

Tags: python, regex, expression, line

I would like to use regular expressions to delete all lines that start with a '!', except the last one that starts with this character. Additionally all empty lines should be deleted.

! row 1

!that is row number 2

!  - another row

! a b c d

0 1 2 3

4 5 6 7

8 9 10 11

desired output:

a b c d

0 1 2 3

4 5 6 7

8 9 10 11

So far, I got:

```
re.sub(r'(?m)^(?!.*a\sb\sc\sd)\#.*\n?', '', textstring)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?:.*\n)+!([^!]*)`

You can test it in https://regex101.com/

[image: test it in regex101]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\A(?:!.*\n)+!\s*(.*a\sb\sc\sd)', r'\1', textstring)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x9QgfY/1). *Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `(?:!.*\n)+` - one or more lines starting with `!`
- `!` - a `!`,
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*a\sb\sc\sd)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, `a`, whitespace, `b`, whitespace, `c`, whitespace, `d`.

The replacement is the Group 1 value, `\1`.